# Writing a field formatter for D6

Tags: 6, entities

So I'm almost embarrassed to ask this, but it's been so long since I've touched Drupal 6. We've been asked for something which requires another Field Formatter for a File field.

Form the code below, I'm able to select `File download formatter` in Content Type Display. However, when looking at the rendered page, I see no output for this field.

During `drush cc all` I see the reponse "TEST ONE" print in the console denoteing that MODULE_theme() is running. But there is not a connection to  `theme_MODULE_viewer`.

Once I get this wired up, I'm sure I can finish this in a hour, but what am I missing?

```
<?php
**
* Implementation of hook_field_formatter_info().
*/
function MODULE_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    'socf' => array(
      'label' => t('File download formatter'),
      'field types' => array('filefield'),
      'description' => t('TO DO: add description'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
* Implements hook_theme().
*/
function MODULE_theme() {

  print "TEST ONE";

  return array(
    'MODULE_viewer' => array(
      'arguments' => array('element' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}

function theme_MODULE_viewer($element) {

  print "TEST TWO";
  return 'Future response here. ';
}
```

From my understanding `hook_theme` creates an awareness of `theme_MODULE_viewer` in the array key `MODULE-viewer`.

In the Devel Tab, I see that the field contains data in both Load and Render panels.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did this in a slightly different way. By using `hook_preprocess_content_field()`, I search through all of the fields in a node and do a `str_replace()` on those items. This does solve my problem but I'm open to a more elegant solution.

```
function MODULE_preprocess_content_field(&$variables) {

  for ($i=0; $i < count($variables['items']); $i++) {
    $searchfor = variable_get('file_directory_path') . '/special_folder';
    $replacewh = 'portfolio/asset';
    $variables['items'][$i]['filepath'] = str_replace($searchfor, $replacewh, $variables['items'][$i]['filepath']);
    $variables['items'][$i]['view'] = str_replace($searchfor, $replacewh, $variables['items'][$i]['view']);
  }
}
```

Side note: The path portfolio/asset is part of this same module and defined in `hook_menu`. I would have preferred to have this done with a field formatter in the above code, but I've got to move on.